Does Filling weight paint have auto normalize option?
Hi I would like to know if I can fill weight with shortcut "shift+K" as auto normalized.
I could get ideal result if I do this after filling weight,
weights menu>Normalize All (select:Defrom Pose Bones, Lock Active :On)
sometimes I forget this step and missing clearness of my weighting process.
so I hope if filling weights also has auto normalize option.



I can't find anything bound to Shift K, even with factory settings. And what you show in your screenshots doesn't look like a "filling". So what function are you talking about? You screenshots look more like a gradient. Neither the gradient tool nor the radial/linear gradient operators make use of auto normalization. AFAIK only the paint tool makes use of it.
